# SmtpClient SendAsync blocks UI-Thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, smtpclient

I am sending a mail with `SmptClient` which takes ~1minute.

To not block my UI-Thread I use `sendasync()` but without success. My GUI is blocked. Code:

```
MailMessage email = new MailMessage();
...
Attachment attachement = new Attachment(attachementfile);
Email.Attachments.Add(attachement);

SmtpClient mailClient = new SmtpClient(host, port);
mailClient.Timeout = 300000;  
mailClient.SendCompleted += (s, e) =>
                {
                    email.Dispose();
                }; 

mailClient.SendAsync(email, null);  // very bad processing of events till completed
```

I also tried using Backgroundworker but UI is still blocked.

EDIT: I have the same problem with FTP upload. I use .NET 3.5

Comment: So the call to `mailClient.SendAsync` is the line that blocks?

Comment: yes. it does not block complete but near complete (very bad processing of events)

Comment: if it doesn't block completely, maybe you have shortage of system resources which makes sending a mail a hard operation causing "very bad processing of events till completed"? Check the process monitor.

Comment: that is not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It sound strange, especially given that you have tried Background worker approach.
Just as a bare bones solution, you can throw it to threadpool and then it will not block UI thread for sure:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem( (state) => 
{
    try {
          mailClient.SendAsync(email, null);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
          // Log ex
    }
});
```

If this blocks - it means that your ThreadPool is full and you are using too many threads in the application.